# kbskit build for different linux flavours

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, starkit

I am creating a kbskit for my tcl executable application as follows on Suse :

```
./kbs.tcl -builddir=85 -r -mk-bi -bi="itcl3.4 itk3.4 iwidgets4.0.2 img1.4.1" install kbskit8.5 

cp 85/bin/kbsmk8.5-bi kbsmk8.5-bi-run 

./kbsmk8.5-bi sdx.kit wrap sim -runtime kbsmk8.5-bi-run
```

The application will be used on several flavours of linux like Redhat,Ubuntu etc. I am trying my best to test it myself under many combinations. Neverthless, i would be like to know someone thinks this would/wouldn’t work seamlessly across different platforms since I wont be able to cover all combinations exhaustively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Linux/x86 kbskit is at least *reasonable* to run on that collection of platforms. Unfortunately, the only way to be sure is to try. It should work, but if *your script* refers to files in a particular location and another platform (or deployment!) puts them elsewhere, then things will fail. The other thing that might go wrong is if there are significant incompatibilities in the small number of system libraries that Tcl uses, especially the C library; I do not know whether such problems exist, but I suspect they're not a major problem in practice.

You can try using the `platform` package (a standard part of Tcl since at least 8.5) to report what platform you're dealing with. That's the usual level of granularity you need to pay attention to.

```
package require platform
puts [platform::identify]
```

Comment: Thanks .. I tried to use the executable on redhat .. it gave me some glibc errors which were gone once i re-built the kbskit on redhat .. so i guess i will have to do it the hard way and re-build for once on each platform without getting into further complexities!